# shiny dashboard to visualise RNA seq data

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am trying to build a shiny dashboard for the visualization of different RNAseq data sets.

However, I am encountering problem with reactive input, the code is always using the second dataset that I have loaded/read in. Anyone has faced a similar issue? If yes, how did you resolve it.

My code is

```
    library(shinydashboard)
library(uwot)
library(DESeq2)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(DESeq2)
library(pheatmap)
library(DEGreport)
library(vsn)
library(RColorBrewer)
library("genefilter")
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(fgsea)
library(clusterProfiler)
library(ggplot2)


set_1<-load("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData2.RData")
set_2<-load("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData1.RData")
data_list = list(set_1=set_1,set_2=set_2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Data Visualizer", titleWidth = 300),
    dashboardSidebar(
        width = 300,
        sidebarMenu(

            menuItem("Datasets",  icon = icon("cog"),
                     selectInput("Datasets", "Datasets:", choices = list("sample1" = "set_1", "sample2" = "set_2"),
                                 selected = "set_1")),
            menuItem("Quality Control", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
            menuItem("Differential Genes", tabName = "widgets2", icon = icon("th")),
            menuItem("Downstream", tabName = "widgets3", icon = icon("th"))
            
         )
    ),
    ## Body content
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            # First tab content
            # Second tab content
            tabItem(tabName="widgets",
                   h2("widgets"),
                   plotOutput("widgets"),
                    
            ),
            tabItem(tabName = "widgets2",
                    h2("Widgets2 tab content"),
                    
            ),
            tabItem(tabName = "widgets3",
                    h2("Widgets3 tab content"),
                    plotOutput("widgets3"),
                    
            )

        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    
    datasetInput <- reactive({
        df <- data_list[[input$Datasets]]
        })
    
        output$widgets <- renderPlot({
            datasetInput()
            par(mfrow=c(1,2))
            
            boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=F), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Without Normalization")
            boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=T), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Normalized")
            
            })
        
        }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I can see.

The first is that the results are loaded via `RData` files, which include information about the variable names. Assuming these work, I expect they create a variable within the R environment called `dds` which has the DESeq2 results. The second load overwrites that variable:

```
set_1<-load("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData2.RData")
set_2<-load("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData1.RData")
```

What should probably be done is storing the results as an R Dataset that doesn't include variable name information:

```
# create set_1 DESeq2 results called 'dds'
saveRDS(dds, "C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData2.rds")
# create set_2 DESeq2 results called 'dds'
saveRDS(dds, "C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData1.rds")
```

Then those can be loaded into the R environment using the assignment you expect:

```
set_1<-readRDS("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData2.RData")
set_2<-readRDS("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData1.RData")
data_list = list(set_1=set_1,set_2=set_2)
```

The second issue is that the plot output displays `dds`, rather than the `datasetInput` variable, and there is no assignment to change the definition of `dds`:

```
    output$widgets <- renderPlot({
        dds <- datasetInput() ## Note: added assignment
        par(mfrow=c(1,2))
        
        boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=F), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Without Normalization")
        boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=T), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Normalized")
        
        })
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, your tips were very helpful